# How to get current windows user in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I tried lots of code it Works successfuly in my local server. But I tried it to put remote server they get another strings such as IIS APPPOOL, "servername" .... I change to some settings in IIS manager but I failed.
How can i get username in remote server

I tried some codes like:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;

  string strName = p.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
string strName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

or

```
string Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
```

or

```
string Name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

or

```
WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    string usernamex = currentIdentity.Name.ToString();
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the authentication setting on IIS?

Comment: `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` should work fine. Please do mention your authentication settings in IIS as well.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User` should work *if* you have the correct authentication settings  and the user has logged in. If you have anonymous authentication enabled, no user authentication takes place and the application pool's account is used instead. If you use any other type of authentication, `HttpContext.Current.User` will return the logged in user. If you have both anonymous and something else, anonymous overrides the other choices

Comment: I tried both of them it work in my local server but it does not work in remote server. Also, I don't know what to do in IIS Manager.

Comment: in IIS Manager settings Windows authentication is enabled

Comment: Anonymous authentication must also be disabled, otherwise it takes precedence - web browsers always try to connect anonymously first

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using IIS 7.5 do the following. Other versions will be similar. All the above ways of getting the username should then work.

```
1) Double click on Authentication (This can be done at server level and your web site level so check both!)
2) Right click on Anonymous authentication and disable it and likewise enable Windows authentication
3) Click Basic settings. Check which application pool your website is using. Ensure it is using pass-through authentication for an "Application User" by clicking "Connect As" i.e. A user using a browser will be the person requesting authentication.
4) Click "Application Pools". Click the Application pool from (3). Click "Advanced Settings". Check the Identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity
```

[image: Double click on Authentication]

[image: Right click on Anonymous authentication and disable it and likewise enable Windows authentication]

[image: Check which application pool your website is using]
[image: Check the Application pool settings]

Comment: thanks a lot sarin but I don't understand   Why I am getting set Anonymous  authentication disable. and it does not work still. I can't get the username of Windows user

Comment: Did you disable Anonymous authentication on both the server and the web site ? my picture above only shows clicking on the server, but you definitely need to click on the web site and disable it from there. The server is optional as you may want other web sites you host to work differently.

Comment: When Anonymous authentication is disable  web site wants to get but I want to enter the password for authentication. And How can i set both server and web site ?

Comment: Yes. There is an authentication element with Mode="Windows". If it's not working best thing to do is build a small test app and deploy it to remove all of your application logic and be sure it is setup related. Try this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323176

Comment: The real question is that how can i get username without authentication ?  Icannot understand it sorry sarin

Answer (score 3):

`HttpContext.Current.User` should be ok, but the fact that *Windows authentication is enabled* it's not enough: also ensure anonymous authentication is disabled.